# Error 404 for Search Form

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I get a Error 404 when i try to search for something on my site my search form code looks like this

```
<form method="get" class="search-form" id="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php _e('Search form', 'fukasawa'); ?>" name="s" id="s" />
<a id="searchsubmit" class="search-button" onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit(); return false;"><div class="genericon genericon-search"></div></a>
```

I redirected my homepage site to another url so im gussomg that thats the issue for example

Mysite example.com is now redirected to example.com/front-page

so when i search for something it now adds the /front-page with it.

where as before it was just the Mysite example.com and the search without /front-page

i made the redirection cause my site becomes unresponsive sometimes and i get a blank page

here is the code i used to redirect my site in the htaaccess folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/front-page [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Add a `RewriteCond` to ensure the `QUERY_STRING` is empty.

Comment: did what you said i get a Internal Server Error

Comment: Did you add the `RewriteCond` this way? `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`